# Facing issue when try add logs in cucumber js using nodejs

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

When i do regression testing it says this error in any steps
`Cannot attach when a step/hook is not running`.

How can i solve some times it didn't give me line where its happens.

```
at AttachmentManager.onAttachment (/home)
          at AttachmentManager.createStringAttachment (/home/engine/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/attachment_manager/index.js:99:14)
          at AttachmentManager.create (/home/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/attachment_manager/index.js:63:22)
          at AttachmentManager.log (/home/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/runtime/attachment_manager/index.js:37:21)
          at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/features/step_definitions/minimum_requirements_stepdef.js:669:19)
          at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
          at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```